# How to implement this simple jQuery image gallery?

Tags: jquery, image-gallery

I'm trying to make a simple jQuery gallery with only 3 images as pictured below.

[image]

I translated it like this :

```
if thumb clicked -> this thumb -> become big
current big -> become thumb
```

The problem is that I don't know how is the way I translated it seems correct ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Simple Gallery</title>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    function ChangeThis(getThumb)
    {
        for(var i=1;i<=3;i++)
        {
            if(getThumb == i)
            {
                $("#bigView").html("<img src='img"+i+"' />");
                $("#thumb"+i).hide();
            }
            else
            {
                $("#thumb"+i).show();
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<style>
#bigView{width:100px;height:100px;}
.thumb{width:30px;height:30px}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table><tr><td colspan="3">
<div id="bigView"><img src='img1'></div>
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td><div id="thumb1" class="thumb" onclick="ChangeThis(1);" style="display:none;"><img src='img1' /></div></td>
<td><div id="thumb2" class="thumb" onclick="ChangeThis(2);"><img src='img2' /></div></td>
<td><div id="thumb3" class="thumb" onclick="ChangeThis(3);"><img src='img3' /></div></td>
</tr>
</table>
```